# Отступ в зависимости от времени

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Помогите найти решение:

Нужно изменять отступ с лева и ширину в зависимости от значений

есть 2 значения

время в формате 10:00(пример) отвечает за отступ с лева

и второе значение в формате 50 мин(пример) отвечает за ширину блока

так вот у нас есть блок его ширина равна 16-ти часам от 10:00 до 01:00

а в этом блоке список блоков которые имеют эти 2 значения которые должны изменять ширину и отступ от левого края в зависимости от данных которые в них есть 
для понимание задачи прикрепляю скрин http://joxi.ru/GrqjJyPcQOME9m

я уже пробовал гуглить но нету результатов вот думаю как сделать расчет отступа и ширины)

Как бы 960 вариантов писать не очень)

Заранее благодарен за ответы и понимание)

Comment: Что вы уже сделали и что не получилось? Т.к. по мне - это не вопрос, а уже часть оплачиваемой работы.

Comment: мне нужны идеи как сделать расчет) мне не нужно чтобы вы писали мне код)

Comment: Варианты решения - разные. Например. создать массив вида {"item_1": {"start_at":"10:00"; "long": "50"}, "item_2": {"start_at":"11:40"; "long": "120"}}. Дальше бы взял div длинной например в 960px, где 1px=1 минута времени и в цикле перебирал этот массив. Например, item_2.start_at - это 1:40 от начала, если перевести - это 100 минут. Значит, взять div и сделать ему отступ 100px слева, а свойство *width* присвоить ему значением *item_2.long*, т.е. 120px.

Comment: хмм то есть берем 10:00 как отправную точку и сравниваем с данными которые получили к примеру 12:30 и разницу(150мин.) переводим в пиксели верно?

Comment: Как вариант - да. Т.к. в задаче не было обусловлено начальной точки. Так, можно взять любое время, за исходную точку, например, полночь (0:00). Это зависит от условий задачи.

Comment: ну в принципе я понял)
Огромное спасибо вам за идею))

Comment: Почему "с лева" написано отдельно, а "отступ" - вместе?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нуууу, думаю так:

1. Берем промежуток от 10:00 до 01:00. Тоесть 10:00 - 0%, 18:00 - 50% и т.д.
2. Берем время, к примеру 13:30. Для удобства будем считать в часах (можно и в минутах). 13:30 - это (13:30-10:00) 3 с половиной часа. Отступ слева = 3.5 / 16 = 0.21875 = 21.875%
3. Берем продолжительность, к примеру 55 минут. В часах это будет 0.917 часов. Приводим опять в относительную ширину - 0.917 / 16 = 0.0573125 = 5.73%

В итоге у нас будет некий блок, у которого `position: absolute; left: 21.875%; width: 5.7%;`
Логочно, у родительського елемента должен быть `position: relative` как минимум.

Вот пример кода:

```js
function HHMMToFloat(s) {
  s = s.split(":");
  return parseInt(s[0]) + parseInt(s[1]) / 60;
}

var START = HHMMToFloat("10:00");
var END = 24 + HHMMToFloat("01:00");
var FULL = END - START + 1;

function getElementSizes(time, duration) {
  time = HHMMToFloat(time) - START;
  if (time < 0) time += 24;
  duration = HHMMToFloat(duration);

  var left = time / FULL * 100;
  var width = duration / FULL * 100;

  return `position: absolute; left: ${left}%; width: ${width}%;`;
}

console.log(getElementSizes("13:30", "00:55"))
console.log(getElementSizes("00:00", "01:00"))
console.log(getElementSizes("10:00", "16:00"))
```